# git: al hacer push sube los archivos a mi repo, pero con un usuario anterior que yo tenia

Tags: git, github, git-push

Buenas tardes, tengo el problema que cuando hago un git push en el github me aparece que eso lo subio un usuario anterior que yo tenia, nose porq pasa ni como arreglarlo en el  git config user.name lo tengo configurado a mi usuario actual.

Comment: desde donde estas haciendo el push!? desde el power shell o el git de escritorio !?

Comment: Recuerda que hay 2 formas de subir, SSH key / HTTPS puede ser el caso que este reconociendo el SSH que tienes con tu usuario anterior.

Comment: te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder amigos, Rostan hago el push desde el power shell uso win10 y JCTimmypage estoy haciendo el push por https, tenia una sshkey pero la borre habra alguna manera de borrar toda esa configuracion  anterior.. ?

Answer (score 3):

En Git puedes configurar el numbre del usuarios y el correo electrónico de quien hace los cambios, a nivel global o diferenciado por repositorio.

Para hacerlo de forma global basta que hagas algo como esto:

```
PS C:\ruta\cualquiera> git config --global user.name "wilmugo"
PS c:\ruta\cualquiera> git config --global user.email "wilmugo@example.com"
```

Para hacerlo diferenciado por repositorio, omite la bandera **`--global`**, por ejemplo:

```
PS C:\ruta\al\repositorio\específico> git config user.name "wilmugo"
PS c:\ruta\al\repositorio\específico> git config user.email "wilmugo@example.com"
```